# Problemas com cache no google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, cache

Estou fazendo umas alterações num site e essas alterações envolvem páginas em ASP Clássico e Javascript. O que está passando é que sempre altero o javascript, salvo e jogo ele no meu servidor ele não atualiza. Ele sobrescreve o antigo, porém quando vou utilizar as alterações realizadas ele continua referenciando a versão anterior. Para resolver isso tenho sempre que reiniciar a máquina, aí sim, as alterações feitas são utilizadas. Como eu sempre trabalho com o Dev Tools do Chrome aberto, eu marquei a opção `Cache Disabled`, mas mesmo assim não funcionou, só reiniciando a máquina. Alguém sabe o que tenho que fazer para resolver esse problema que me incomoda? Reiniciar um máquina hoje, demando pelo menos entre 5 a 20 min, fazendo isso umas 10 a 15 vezes por dia, isso é um tempo perdido muito grande.

Comment: Não sei te ajudar quanto ao cache, mas uma pequena gambiarra para você não ter que ficar reiniciando toda hora é toda vez que atualizar o seu js trocá-lo de nome, e na página que o referencia também.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, nem pensar. Você não tem noção do tamanho disso aqui e vários sites, que estão à minha disposição o utiliza esse e outros arquivos. É muito grande. Só para ter uma idéia, mexemos num módulo em ASP, mas tem Java, Asp.Net. É um ninho de cobras isso aqui. Temos algumas vezes que duplicar arquivos, pois não temos como alterar uma página, pois muitas delas são chamadas em vários lugares. Isso não tem nem como cogitar.

Comment: Eu também não aconselho. Mas já fiz isso e depois voltei pro nome original porque de jeito nenhum o código atualizava.

Answer (score 0):

Se o Cache disabled não funcionou vou orientar a limpar o cache manualmente ou mesmo usar uma extensão para limpar o cache sempre como o [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap).

Comment: Ok, tenho problemas aqui na empresa para instalar o cache killer. Já falei com os caras que administram, pois o chrome aqui na empresa tem muitas restrições, diferente do IE. Mas assim que os caras que derem permissão para instalar, farei os testes e se der certo, posto o resultado e encerro o post.

Comment: Não sei se isso tem a ver com tudo, mas sempre que eu reinicio a máquina, quando testo não funciona. Porém após uns minutos, depois de reiniciada, aí funciona. Observei isso pela segunda vez, coincidência ou não, coloco isso como subsídio para tentar solucionar o problema que eu tenho aqui. Parece bizarro, mas é a segunda vez que observo em duas vezes que reiniciei a máquina.

Comment: Pode então limpar manualmente a cada vez como indiquei.

Comment: Como limpar manualmente? Com Ctrl+F5? Dessa forma não funciona. Só funciona reiniciando.

Comment: @pnet Vi que postou limpar manualmente, tenta o control + R

Answer (score 0):

o problema está resolvido, mas uma coisa não conseguir entender. Possivelmente já estivesse assim e só agora notei. O seguinte: Eu dou `Ctrl+R`, `Ctrl+F5`, `Recarregar` e nada. Bem, fiz isso ontem e nada dava certo, continuava com o arquivo .js não atualizado. Bem, depois de uns 20min observei que funcionou. Fiz outra atualização no arquivo e fiz todo esse processo e não atualizou. Aí lembrei dessa espera, deixei lá e depois de uns 30min, fui testar e funcionou. Hoje a mesma coisa aconteceu, logo alguma coisa que eu não sei o que é está tipo, "travando" a atualização e depois, sei lá o que, funciona. Talvez seja possível que nem precise descarregar cache, ou seja, depois de um tempo o próprio browser reconhece as alterações. Parece estranho, mas é isso que está acontecendo aqui. É só esperar que volta a funcionar. Tudo isso sem reiniciar a máquina. Closed case.

Comment: Isso pode ser cache do lado do servidor, ou também cache do proxy caso a sua rede use algum tipo de proxy.